# FullCalendar : How to Add/Edit events without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I have implemented fullcalender version 5 in out project.page refreshes on each event add/edit.i dont want it to happen.can any one suggest me how to resolve this issue.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        now: '',
        editable: true,
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimelineDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
        },
        resources: <?php eventGroups(); ?>,
        events: <?php eventGroupsDetails(); ?>,
        dateClick: function(info) {
            $('#addScheduleEntry').modal('show');
        },
    });
    calendar.render();
});

function eventGroupsDetails() {
    echo '[';
    $event = '';
    $event_qry = "SELECT * FROM st_Event WHERE 1=1 AND status=1 ORDER BY event_id DESC limit 5";
    $event_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $event_qry);
    while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($event_query)) {
        $event_id = $arr['event_id'];
        $user_id = $arr['user_id'];
        $event_title = $arr['event_title'];
        if ($event_title == "") {
            $event_title = $arr['event_job_id'];
        }
```

Comment: you would need to use AJAX. Since you haven't showed any of the existing code for adding/editing events, we cannot really give you any more specific guidance than that. You've tagged AJAX in your question, so you are clearly aware of it. Therefore it's unclear where you are actually stuck in implementing your requirement, or what you have tried so far, or what the specific problem is. Can you clarify your question please?

Comment: events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
 successCallback(<?php eventGroupsDetails($fromDate,$toDate); ?>)
},
dateClick: function(info) {
   $.ajax({
        url: "calendar_event_create.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#frmEvent").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
         calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        }
    });
},

Comment: Currently while adding events we get success response for each event that we add.can you guide us how to call event successcallback function.we want to implement this because user does not want to reload/refresh page every time they add eventes and fullcalender does not have any specific guidelines clarification for this "successCallback" function.

Comment: Please add your code attempt into the question. As you can see yourself, code posted in the comments is quite hard to read. In the question you can format them properly like your other code.

Comment: Anyway from what I _can_ see, that attempt is not using AJAX. It's functionally no different than your previous version.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there is no guidance - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function even has a code example showing you how to use it That example is more complex than most code will need to be, since it's also parsing an XML file, but if you make your PHP code return JSON then you can ignore that bit.

Comment: However, you likely don't even need the events function. Just use this approach instead, it's much simpler: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed . That way you don't have to write the AJAX call yourself, all you need to do is create a PHP script which will return the JSON data when fullCalendar calls it.

Comment: Hi, my questions is when event added then after hoe to get new added events display on fullcaleander without page refresh.

Comment: I know your question already. I'm trying to give you the information so you understand how to solve it. Was there something in my comments, or in the links I've given you, which you specifically were confused by? I'm not sure which part of this you are stuck with now. My last comment in particular (the one starting with "However..." should really tell you everything you need. Was something not clear from that? Did you try to use that information to change your code?

Comment: hi any guide provide to information when event add ,update or resize then update into database and display in calendar without page refresh.i'm using version 5.

Comment: Again, you should use Ajax. Where are you stuck exactly? And please ask a new question about it, since it's a new topic. Post your code there, and include the code which contains your attempt at solving the problems. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Bro ADyson thank you for help we have successfully complete this issue resolve. thank you.